# Was the idea of pre-Empire Old Jedi Order members not being allowed to marry mentioned in before-prequels EU books?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

From this SFF [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24494/976):

> Out of universe, the idea of the Jedi order as a monastic organization praising celibacy was a new concept introduced, if I remember correctly, in Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones or around that time. Anyway, Luke made his marriage proposal to Mara in Timothy Zahn's Vision of the Future, published in September 1998, half a year before the release of Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace.

I can swear I recall reading in one of pre-preqel EU books discussion on the topic of pre-Empire Jedi not being allowed to marry. May or may not have been related to some Holocron that Luke found. I don't recall if it was in context of Mara Jade.

I'm looking for someone to confirm whether that recollection is correct with an example.

Comment: And if you are wrong, what would you accept as a proof? In [Children of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Jedi#Continuity_issues), published in 1995 "there are [Continuity] issues with the description of the members of the Old Jedi Order as depicted here, specifically their decentralized structure **and acceptance of family and relationship ties.** "

Comment: @DavRob60 - hm. Tough one. A grep of all pre-prequel EU novels would do it. Except I don't have mine anymore in soft copy, and hardcopies are all packed up into boxes :(

Comment: Hm. Humbly's mention of marriages is not a bad evidence, but not quite bulletproof evidence that none of EU discussed marriage bans. Especially since it was noted to have been a "rogue sect"

Comment: This "rogue sect" thing is a retcon. The sources (*The New Essential Guide to Characters (2002)* and *The Clone Wars: No Prisoners (2009)*) were published after the prequels.

Comment: By the way, this question could be reformulated as "What was the first reference to the idea that pre-Empire Old Jedi Order members were not allowed to marry?" To which I answerer "Attack of the Clones".

Comment: @DavRob60 - feel free to edit - I don't object to your wording at all :)

Comment: Prior to Mara - years prior, in Darksaber (1995), Luke had plans to marry Callista. And Callista, being a pre-Purge Jedi, had no qualms about it. In fact, she insisted that a Jedi Master must mate with a strong Force-user to produce powerful children.

Answer (score 3):

> The Jedi Order was founded in 25,783 BBY, and their philosophies --
>   such as the distinction between the light side and dark side of the
>   Force -- developed over the next few centuries. They served as the
>   guardians of the Republic since its foundation. It wasn't until around
>   4,000 BBY, however, that the Jedi began to forbid marriage and
>   attachment.
>
> Practically speaking, this is due to the structure of the Expanded
>   Universe. Before the Prequels came out, EU writers had to avoid the
>   Prequel Era so as to avoid contradictions with later material. For the
>   most part, the EU covered events in between the Original Trilogy
>   movies and after Return of the Jedi. In order to explore new time
>   periods and characters, works like Knights of the Old Republic were
>   set 4,000 to 5,000 years before A New Hope and featured Jedi marrying
>   with no problem. When the prohibition of marriage was revealed in
>   Episode II, it only made sense in the EU if it started after 4,000
>   BBY.
>
> In-universe, the new rule prohibiting marriage is justified by changes
>   in the structure of the Jedi Council and Jedi Order. Before 4,000 BBY,
>   the Jedi Order was made up of loosely affiliated local groups. After
>   the Great Sith War, they became a unified organization under the Jedi
>   High Council, which began to reinterpret the Jedi Code. Among the new
>   regulations were the prohibition of marriage and the idea that Jedi
>   must begin their training as very young children.

Source: http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsglossaryandfaq/a/Star-Wars-FAQ_Why-Cant-Jedi-Marry.htm

> Another difference in the portrayal of the Jedi pre- and post-1999 is
>   the existence of Jedi families. During the Bantam era, it was
>   established that Jedi could marry and have families, and several of
>   the characters were the descendants of Jedi Knights, including Kam
>   Solusar (Dark Empire II; Veitch, 1994) and Corran Horn (I, Jedi;
>   Stackpole, 1998). Callista had a spouse named Geith Eris, and the
>   Imperial warship Eye of Palpatine was meant to attack Belsavis, a
>   planet housing the children of Jedi Knights (Children of the Jedi;
>   Hambly, 1995). Jedi of the Old Republic during the Sith Era also had
>   families; Andur and Nomi Sunrider were married and had a daughter,
>   Vima (Tales of the Jedi: The Saga of Nomi Sunrider; Veitch, 1993).
>   Then, Episode II firmly established the idea that Jedi could not marry
>   nor have children, due to the risks of falling to the Dark Side
>   associated with attachment to your spouse/offspring. Also, according
>   to Vergere, Jedi were not permitted to have children to avoid creating
>   Jedi family dynasties, which would have undue influence in the Order
>   (I think this was from Destiny’s Way; Williams, 2002). As a result,
>   retcons were required. Ranik Solusar had his son Kam without the
>   permission of the Jedi Council, and so was severely reprimanded (The
>   New Essential Guide to Characters; Wallace, 2002). There were two
>   interpretations of Corran Horn’s circumstance. Either Nejaa Halcyon
>   had special dispensation to have his son Valin (who became Hal Horn,
>   Corran’s father) due to cultural considerations (Elusion Illusion;
>   Stackpole, 2003) or Halcyon married and had a child without
>   permission, keeping it hidden from the Jedi Council (Jedi Trial;
>   Sherman and Cragg, 2004). Ultimately, any Jedi offspring dating from
>   that era (such as Galen Marek) could be explained by the child being
>   conceived with special dispensation from, or against the will of, the
>   Jedi Council. Callista and Geith were members of Djinn Altis’s Jedi
>   sect, which allowed marriage (Order 66; Traviss, 2008). The children
>   of the Jedi located on Belvasis were retconned into being Apprentices
>   and Padawans, not offspring (The New Essential Guide to Characters;
>   Wallace, 2002). Last, issue 23 of Knights of the Old Republic
>   established that there was a shift in Jedi thinking following the
>   Great Sith War (J. Miller, 2007). Jedi would continue to have
>   relationships and families for some years; Grand Master Satele Shan
>   had a son, Theron (The Old Republic 7; Freed, 2011), but by the time
>   of the Ruusan Reformations, the Jedi Order would ban marriage and
>   conception.

source: http://www.eucantina.net/archives/11067

Comment: Sorry, but how is this even remotely addressing my question of "was there a specific mention of Jedi prohibition on marriage in EU pre-prequel"? Someone writing an article on about.com saying 'When the prohibition of marriage was revealed in Episode II' is as authoritative as DavRob's original answer I quoted - less so, in fact, since I know DavRob's level of knowledge of EU and don't know the about.com author's; and the article has no references or proof.

Comment: I added a source that might help answer the question more closely. I can verify that the pre-1999 novel summaries are correct, as I read those novels several times. I'm a little hazy on the post-1999 novels, as I haven't read them nearly as much.

Comment: Much more improved. I'm still very sure that I've seen SOME mention of non-marriage in EU, but this does a good job or removing a vast majority of books (aside from Zahn's) that I would have seen it in. +1

Comment: Is there a `tl;dr` version of these quotes?