# If mastery of the Force is hereditary, how are the Jedi so numerous?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, star-wars-legends

I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer to this anywhere on the web. While [this SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24492/why-can-jedi-marry-in-the-new-jedi-order) poses a related question, I don't think it sufficiently answers mine...

During the opening chapters of *Jedi Search*, Luke addresses the new Senate on the need to find new Jedi talent, or Force sensitive individuals. During this proposal, he cites that the most fruitful leads of Jedi potential are in the descendants of Jedi Knights: as Force sensitivity is hereditary. The book even discusses the notion that Leia should be comparatively well attuned to the Force, due to her being the child of Anakin Skywalker.

I understand that the concept of the Jedi as a totally celibate and monastic order was something that was retconned into the lore after *Episode II: Attack of the Clones*, and that there are examples of entire nuclear Jedi families exist (such as Andur Sunrider and Plo Koon)...

But if Force-manipulative ability is passed down genetically (as a potentially mutative property of their genetic makeup), why would the Jedi order be so numerous if they practice Chastity?

Even if procreation is not expressly forbidden (as in the pre-retcon Expanded Universe): why would Jedi need special permission to produce more Jedi potential children?

How are more Jedi created, if not through procreation? Has their profusion been deliberately retarded, and if so why? is there another explanation for their (pre-empirical) plenitude?

Comment: Hereditary just means it is passed down through blood. I would bet there are numerous individuals across the galaxy that have the ability to become Jedi, but unless it is recognized they never will. Anakin only did because a couple Jedi accidentally bumped into him on a planet and took the time to get to know him; otherwise he would have died likely never knowing the full extent of his abilities...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jedi don't have to be celibate. In 2002, George Lucas is [quoted as saying](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/1989505.stm):

> "Jedi Knights aren't celibate - the thing that is forbidden is attachments - and possessive relationships."

The article goes on to say that "Jedi were permitted to have sex."

Comment: Thus doesn't really answer the question asked. Lucas was talking about edge cases, not what the majority of Jedi do.

Comment: In the movies, we know of four individuals' parents. Three (Kylo Ren, Luke, and Leia) had a Jedi as a father or grandfather. The fourth, Anakin, was said to be conceived by midichlorians and (non-validated) Fan Theory suggests this was due in part to Palpatine (a Sith).

Since _every_ case we know falls under this, I'm tempted to believe it is not such an edge case.

Comment: And while that's true, none of those births were sanctioned by the Jedi.

Comment: @Lan can you direct me to more information about the fan theory regarding the connection between Palpatine and the conception of Anakin? Thanks

Comment: @Withywindle Allegedly, in the original script for Episode 3, Palpatine explains "I used the power of the Force to will the midi-chlorians to start the cell divisions that created you, You might say I'm your father" (http://www.cracked.com/article_23432_7-insanely-awful-ideas-that-almost-ended-up-in-star-wars.html).

Comment: @Withywindle The second part of the theory is that Palpatine's old master Plagueis "was a Dark Lord of the Sith so powerful and so wise, he could use the Force to influence the midi-chlorians to create life." Palpatine's son Triclops was possibly produced by this. So the theory goes, if Palpatine did this to create one son, it is possible that he did that for another. I don't think it is fleshed out more than that.

Answer (score 23):

The semi-canon "[Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force)" identifies that while Jedi powers *can* be directly hereditary, they can also surface in **any** family, presumably as a result of recessive genes. Case in point would obviously be the [Jedi Hutt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beldorion), Beldorion.

The Jedi Order employed a veritable army of testers and recruiters whose sole job it was to identify those individuals who had sufficient force sensitivity to be trained as Jedi. Not all force-sensitives were recruited. Those whose powers were substandard were left in-situ in the hopes that their offspring would possess greater powers.

[image]

Comment: In addition, the Jedi were not particularly numerous. The galaxy's population was an estimated 100 quadrillion (100,000,000,000,000,000) beings, according to the Star Wars Atlas. Order 66 killed about 99% of the Jedi Order; if we go by Wookiepedia, which indicates around 100 survivors, there were about 10,000 Jedi in the pre-Empire Jedi Order. In other words, Jedi comprised 0.00000000001% of the population.

Comment: @Fatbird3 - The "Jedi Path" manual agrees with you. The Jedi number approx 10,000

Comment: @Fatbird3 wow! If you compare this numbers with an average population like earth (around 6 billion) there is about one Jedi found in the population of several thousand worlds!!! This is not even comparable to "I heard there is one guy with magical powers in the whole US" they are 100.000 times more rare in the galaxy...

Comment: Why is *The Jedi Path* semi-canon? Wasn't it published in 2010?

Comment: @Adamant - It was published under consultation with LucasFilm.

Comment: @Valorum - But wasn’t that before the Great Disney Purge?

Comment: @Adamant - It was indeed, hence only *semi*-canon and possibly not even that. That being said, it's not been contradicted and the writers of the new shows are referring to it when talking about Jedi training, so it's obviously well-respected, even if it's "pre-purge" material.

Answer (score 2):

That is not really true that Jedi must happen in hereditary ways... In fact, if that was the case you might have an army of Jedi. Moreover, you are thinking only Jedi, what would happen to the Sith in that regard? Sith also possess force sensitivity no matter how they chose to use it or which version... And a Sith would not have problems in generating armies in hereditary ways, if it would suit them, even with the strange master and only disciple rule...

I believe it could happen in both ways, spontaneous as a genetic leap (kinda X-Men which need much more training than X-Men naturally would), or as an hereditary trait (which would boost the possibilities of children being born more sensitive) but I don't lock Jedi existence on hereditary traits and transmission only...

Comment: When I refer to Jedi, I am referring to the order. 'Jedi' is not hereditary... force sensitivity **is**, according to *Jedi Search*... infact, it is cited as **the most probable** way of passing its trait on, evolutionarily...(according to the text, at least): Hence the question...

Answer (score 0):

"The most fruitful leads" would be the descendents for one obvious reason. It does run in families and families are relatively easy to trace compared to finding the slightly more than 1 in 1e10 anonymous people out there who are just randomly Force sensitive. That's not to say you can't find a LOT of people that way if you keep at it. The population of Star Wars galaxy being 1e17 the total number available is roughly 10 million.

Comment: This is a great answer, to really blow it out the water can I recommend you provide some sources for your numbers?

Answer (score -1):

Think about the Skywalkers: Vader was a powerful Force User, he himself had a son who was even more powerful, and if Rey is Luke's daughter then she is also a Force User.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer. Furthermore, one example does not make the most convincing argument. Please have a look at [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information about the sort of answer we are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

well in genetics it could  be possible that the force is a rarer recessive allele and it would be impossible to remove everyone with the gene without removing all life in the galaxy. that being said certain people who are jedis would not have to procreate as in time new jedis would be born through random sexual reproduction.  the gene would reappear over a certain period of time. jedis cant be removed